# Is it possible to create a direct link to a modal with React and Meteor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router

I'm having a lot of fun building my first Meteor/React project. I was wondering if there is a way to create a direct link to a modal?

At the moment I have 3 pages which all have their own modals. I would like to create something like www.page.com/comments/modalId. So when people click on the link they are immediatly brought to the specific modal.

I am using react-router for the routing in my app but to be honest I would have no idea how to achieve this, if it's even possible.

Anyone able to push me in the right direction?

Kind regards, 
Dominic

Comment: It's definitely possible. You need to look at the route parameters in js and make the appropriate modal visible.

Comment: Yes that is what I was thinking. So I in my routes I need to have something like /comments/:token But what I was wondering is how do I then
1. Make sure the modal changes state 
2. How does the router know which modal to show? How does it get access to the id of the modal?

Comment: Accessing the route params is a function of the router. Iron-Router and FlowRouter each have their own syntax.

Comment: I guess react-router has the same thing, I'll check that out